# How can I match a given object to a category based on "blueprints" of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to classify objects I receive from clients.

On the server side, I have defined my "blueprints" like so:

```
{ // "type1"
    type: 1,
    name: String,
    password: String
}

{ // "type2"
    type: 2,
    user_id: Number,
    action: String
}

{ // "type3", and yes, this says type: 2....
    type: 2,
    object_id: Number,
    action: String
}
```

Based on what the client sends I want to classify them like this:

```
{ type: 1, name: 'user', password: 'pass' }                    // -> type1
{ type: 1, name: 'user', password: 'pass', remember_me: true } // -> type1
{ type: 2, name: 'user', password: 'pass' }                    // -> N/A
{ type: 2, user_id: 5, action: 'hello' }                       // -> type2
{ type: 2, object_id: 5, action: 'hello' }                     // -> type3
```

The identification would need to be based off of the key names, the data-types of values, and the actual value of the values. There will be thousands of objects sent per second, and there may be thousands of blueprints. Therefore, it would be nice if it could be done in `< O(n)` where n is the number of blueprints.

I am writing this from scratch so the blue prints and metadata can be stored in any datastructures needed.

Thanks for the help. I look forward to hearing ideas on this.

Comment: I think there are some typos here - check the types are correct for type 3 in the explanation and code

Comment: They're just objects, not json objects.

Comment: @AramKocharyan There is no typo. `type3` has key `type` with value `2`. I did this to illustrate that using only the type key for classification is not sufficient. @Jack, sure you are right. The objects are, however, expressed using JSON.

Comment: @Jack thanks for the edit, it looks much more clear.

Comment: Are there ever keys in the data not defined in the "type" ?

Comment: The actual algorithm is actually `O(n x m)` where `n` are the number of blueprints and `m` the average number of fields.

Comment: @gnarf Yes, the user can add extra keys onto the object. So `{ type: 1, name: 'user', password: 'pass', remember_me: true } -> type1` should work as well.

Comment: @Jack I am looking for a solution that is much faster than the complexity you suggest. For instance, assume that the user only sends fields that are defined in the blueprints. You could organize the keys or the received object alphabetically and concatenate them together to create a finger print. So `type3 -> actionobject_idtype` and `{ type: 2, object_id: 5, action: 'hello' } -> actionobject_idtype` The finger print could be used to identify the object in O(m) time, where m is the average number of fields.

Comment: Why are you doing this kind of classification?

Comment: I really feel that everyone else has a pretty solid point.  This whole system is strange, and you really should have better type checking/passing in the transport layer here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Random thought on an approach that might reduce complexity:

The real limiting factor here is going to be how well you can reduce the set of types.  One of the most obvious approaches would be to do something based on only the keys of the object. The problem with having extra keys in the data is that we can't rely on just `Object.keys( data ).sort().join(",")`, we must also try every combination of keys we DO have.

```
// Assuming the "types" list is called "types":
// using underscore.js api
var _ = require('underscore');
var keyMap = _.chain( types ).map(function( typeDef, typeIndex ) {
        // get an index with the definition, in case its 
        return { index: typeIndex, def: typeDef };
    }).groupBy(function( data ) {
        return _.keys( data.def ).sort().join(",");
    }).value();

// empty map needed
keyMap[""] = [];

// assumes sorted key list
function getPossibleMaps( keys ) {
  // if we have a map for this, use it
  if ( keyMap[ keys.join(",") ] ) {
    return keyMap[ keys.join(",") ];
  } else {
    // create a map of possible types by removing every key from the list of keys
    // and then looking for maps that match, cache our result
    return keyMap[ keys.join(",") ] = recursiveMapTest( keys );
  }
}  

function recursiveMapTest( keys ) {
    return _.chain( keys )
      .map(function( key ) {
        return getPossibleMaps( _.without( keys, key ) );
      }).flatten().value();
}

// we must also include "lesser" definitions for each of the key lists we found:
_.each( keyMap, function( results, index ) {
    var keys = index.split(",");
    keyMap[index] = results.concat( recursiveMapTest( keys ) );
});

function getType( data ) {
  function checkType( typeData ) {
    var def = typeData.def;
    return _.every(typeData.def, function( value, key ) {
      // these checks are probably not quite right
      if ( value === null ) {
        return true;
      } else if ( value === Number ) {
        return typeof data[key] === "number" || data instanceof Number;
      } else if ( value === String ) {
        return typeof data[key] === "string" || data instanceof String;
      } else {
        return data[ key ] === value;
      }
    });
  }
  var match = _.find( getPossibleMaps( _.keys( data ).sort() ), checkType );
  return match && match.index;
}

// Retrieve
var clientTypes = [
  { type: 1, name: 'user', password: 'pass' },
  { type: 2, name: 'user', password: 'pass' },
  { type: 2, user_id: 5, action: 'hello' },
  { type: 2, object_id: 5, action: 'hello' },
  { type: 1, name: 'user', password: 'pass', remember_me: true }
];

console.log('Client types:');
for (var i = 0; i < clientTypes.length; i++) {
    var type = clientTypes[i];
    // The type object from the map
    console.log("getType", type, getType(type));
}
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/uvarad/2/edit)

Granted, this just means that the more possible incoming key lists, the more memory you consume storing the "quick" lookup tables.

---

Also, If everything has an numeric type you can obviously use that to speedup a huge chunk of the possible "object types" within that subtype.

---

I think your best bet would be to avoid needing to do any of this in the first place.  Pass better type hints with your objects.

Answer (score 0):

The blueprints will either be sent in an object or an array. If you can send them as an object, use the type IDs as keys and the values as the type object. When determining the type, access the key of that type in `O(1)` time.

Even if you receive the types as an array, an `O(n)` pass will allow you to store them in an object internally and use it as a hash table to retrieve the required type information at runtime.

If you can't rely on the type itself as a key, generate a unique key for each type and use this same function for retrieval.

```
var types = [{ // Will refer to this JSON object as type1
    type: 1,
    name: String,
    password: String
},
{ // type2
    type: 2,
    user_id: Number,
    action: String
},
{ // type3
    type: 2,
    object_id: Number,
    action: String
}];

console.log(types);

// Prepare map
var typeMap = {};
for (var i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
    var type = types[i];
    typeMap[typeKey(type)] = type;
}
console.log(typeMap);

function typeKey(type) {
    var key = '';
    for (var i in type) {
        if (i == 'type') {
            key += type[i].toString() + ':';
        }
        key += ':' + i;
    }
    return key;
}

function getType(type) {
    return typeMap[typeKey(type)];
}

// Retrieve
var clientTypes = [
    { type: 1, name: 'user', password: 'pass' },
    { type: 2, name: 'user', password: 'pass' },
    { type: 2, user_id: 5, action: 'hello' },
    { type: 2, object_id: 5, action: 'hello' }
];
console.log('Client types:');
for (var i = 0; i < clientTypes.length; i++) {
    var type = clientTypes[i];
    // The type object from the map
    console.log(getType(type));
}
```

If a type isn't found for the "client" type, then `undefined` is retured from getType.

http://jsfiddle.net/Kt2sq/1

Output:

```
Client types:
Object {type: 1, name: function, password: function}
undefined
Object {type: 2, user_id: function, action: function}
Object {type: 2, object_id: function, action: function}
```

Comment: The type key of the passed objects can be the same for many different blueprints. I was trying to illustrate that by have `type2` and `type3` have the same value associated with the type key.

Comment: I should have mentioned it in the question, but the user can send fields that are not in the blueprint. For instance `{ type: 1, name: 'user', password: 'pass', remember_me: true } -> type1` should work. I will update the question to reflect this.

Comment: At this point I would suggest assigning IDs to the type and referencing those ids instead of the "type". Otherwise it will be far more complicated trying to work with this data structure. Any solution will be needlessly complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
var obj1={ type: 1, name: 'user', password: 'pass' };
var obj2={ type: 2, name: 'user', password: 'pass' };

//match JSON keys
var keys1 = Object.keys(obj1);
var keys2 = Object.keys(obj2);
if (JSON.stringify(keys1) === JSON.stringify(keys2))
console.log("matched all keys");

//match JSON value datatypes
for (var key in obj1) {
   if (typeof(obj1[key]) == typeof(obj2[key]))
   console.log(key +' data type matched');
}

//match 'type' field
if (obj1.type == obj2.type)
console.log("woooo total match");
```

Here is the time complexity :

1. Key match is O(n)
2. Field data type match is O(n)
3. Type field check is O(1)

So total is O(n) iff JSON is ordered other wise sorting will take additional time.